# android align imageview and text vertically to the center of a layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have an xml layout with an imageview and a text in a linearlayout. On displaying the view, the imageview and the text are layed on a vertical layout but outlined to the left of the screen and some text of the textview is truncated. This is the snippet

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_color_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">
     <!--view active Mechanics-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageCon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imgcon_2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Active Mechanics"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

        <!--view scheduled Mechanics-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageCon2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imgcon_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Scheduled Mechanics"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <!--view completed Mechanics-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageCon3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imgcon_3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Completed Mechanics"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please how can I outline the above in the center vertically of an xml layout.

Comment: try adding `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to the LinearLayout

Comment: change root layout height width to match_parent and set root layout android:gravity="center_vertical" for vertically center all views or android:gravity="center_horizontal" to horizontally center or android:gravity="center" for boh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the width in your `LinearLayout` to  `match_parent` and add the `android:layout_gravity` to center in all `ImageView's`. Try this code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_color_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <!--view active Mechanics-->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/imageCon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imgcon_2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Active Mechanics"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <!--view scheduled Mechanics-->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/imageCon2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imgcon_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Scheduled Mechanics"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <!--view completed Mechanics-->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/imageCon3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imgcon_3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Completed Mechanics"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what has this question done to get a downvote.Please upvote it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add two properties to your root layout in this case its LinearLayout.

> android:layout_width="match_parent"
>
> android:gravity="center"

Example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
          android:background="@drawable/grid_color_selector"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:padding="5dp">
<!--view active Mechanics-->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageCon"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/imgcon_2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Active Mechanics"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<!--view scheduled Mechanics-->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageCon2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/imgcon_1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Scheduled Mechanics"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<!--view completed Mechanics-->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageCon3"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/imgcon_3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Completed Mechanics"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Result:

[image: Preview]